# Disable the Android keyboard on an array of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have an array of EditText and I want to disable the standard keyboard Android that appears every time I click on them.

these are the parts code I am using:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
for (i=0;i<dim*dim;i++){

        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(value[i].getWindowToken(), 0);
        value[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
        value[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        value[i].setOnFocusChangeListener(this);


    }
```

EDIT:

I created a new class, with these lines of code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class KeyboardControlEditText extends EditText {
private boolean mShowKeyboard = false;

public void setShowKeyboard(boolean value) {
    mShowKeyboard = value;
}

// This constructor has to be overriden
public KeyboardControlEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

// Now tell the VM whether or not we are a text editor
@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return mShowKeyboard;
}
}
```

and in my main class in OnCreate:

```
for (i=0;i<dim*dim;i++){

((KeyboardControlEditText) value[i]).setShowKeyboard(false);
value[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
value[i].setOnClickListener(this);


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your own `EditText` class for this. Then, override the default [`onCheckIsTextEditor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onCheckIsTextEditor%28%29) and return `false`.

```
public class NoKeyboardEditText extends EditText {
    // This constructor has to be overriden
    public NoKeyboardEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    // Now tell the VM that we are not a text editor
    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Make sure you substitute in the correct name for the new `EditText`. For example, if your package is `com.example.widget`, you'd want to use `<com.example.widget.NoKeyboardEditText ... />`.

If you need this to be dynamic, you can get even fancier:

```
public class KeyboardControlEditText extends EditText {
    private boolean mShowKeyboard = false;

    public void setShowKeyboard(boolean value) {
        mShowKeyboard = value;
    }

    // This constructor has to be overriden
    public KeyboardControlEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    // Now tell the VM whether or not we are a text editor
    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return mShowKeyboard;
    }
}
```

That way, you can call `((KeyboardControlEditText) myEditText).setShowKeyboard(false);` to change it at runtime.

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I still see the keyboard in Android

Comment: You've changed your XML files to reflect the new class?

Comment: I added in Manifest  the new class. I edited my post with the lines of code that I'm using now in my main class, trying to use his advice.

Comment: When I say "the XML", I mean your layout files. You know, where you've set `<EditText ...`? Those have to be changed to use the new class, instead (as I mentioned between code segments above).

Comment: the whole layout of the activity where I'm working on is dynamically created in Java code

Comment: Okay, then, when you do `new EditText`, change that to `new KeyboardControlEditText`.

Comment: Doing this way will lost the cursor, is there any way to keep the cursor in the text?

Comment: @imrhung Not that I know of.